# firefox/prefs.js does not take modifications

Tags: firefox, sed

I'm trying to change (as root) my firefox settings via prefs.js this way:

```
sed -En '/user_pref\("network\.proxy\.(socks|socks_port|type)"/!p
    $ a\
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");\
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);\
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
    ' prefs.js
```

the output of the script shows it has written correctly in prefs.js, but actually the file does not take the modifications.

Comment: You need to add the `-i` flag to edit in-place: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution with grep and bash:

```
grep -v "network.proxy.\(socks\|socks_port\|type\)" prefs.js  > temp && mv temp prefs.js

cat <<EOT >> prefs.js
user_pref("network.proxy.socks", "x");
user_pref("network.proxy.socks_port", x);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", x);
EOT
```

thanx